# caching of images with tag: eg radar_0.jpg?12345

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am creating a javascript image loop (for a weather radar site), and I'm pre-fetching all 10 images on page load using the following loop:

```
Radar_Images = new Array();
var now = new Date();
for (var i = 0; i <= 9; i++){
     Radar_Images[i] = new Image();
     Radar_Images[i].src = "radar_" + i + ".jpg?" + now.getTime();
}
```

I am adding the "?" + now.getTime(); in order to ensure the browser pulls new copies when it loads the page, and it works properly.  10 new images are downoaded, and the array gets correclty loaded with:

[0] = images/radar_0.jpg?12345 (12345 is just for example... it's actually a 13-digit number)

[1] = images/radar_1.jpg?12345

[2] = images/radar_2.jpg?12345

etc.

Now when I play the javascript animation, looping through the array, it smoothly plays back each cached image.

I have a periodic poll that checks the "Last-Modified" stamp in the radar_0.jpg header using XMLHttpRequest (radar_0.jpg is always the lastest image).  If a new timestamp is detected, it jumps to a function that downloads the new image:

```
var now = new Date();
Radar_Images[9].src = Radar_Images[8].src;
Radar_Images[8].src = Radar_Images[7].src;
Radar_Images[7].src = Radar_Images[6].src;
Radar_Images[6].src = Radar_Images[5].src;
Radar_Images[5].src = Radar_Images[4].src;
Radar_Images[4].src = Radar_Images[3].src;
Radar_Images[3].src = Radar_Images[2].src;
Radar_Images[2].src = Radar_Images[1].src;
Radar_Images[1].src = Radar_Images[0].src;
Radar_Images[0].src = "images/radar_0.jpg?" + now.getTime();
```

What this is meant to do is shuffle the images down one notch, discarding the oldest image, and downloading the update radar_0.jpg image into the [0] slot.  That way, I don't have to re-download all 10 images again, since only one of them has changed.  It works as expected, and here is the updated Array:

[0] = images/radar_0.jpg?67890 <- note the new, unique tag from the now.getTime()

[1] = images/radar_0.jpg?12345 <- this used to be in position 0...

[2] = images/radar_1.jpg?12345 <- this used to be in position 1...

etc.

Here's where the issue crops up.

When I now loop through the images, both Images[0] and Images[1] show the LATEST downloaded image.  Image[1], even though it still points to the older cached image, is lost.  It's as if the browser is forgetting everything after the .jpg? and recognizes them as the same image, radar_0.jpg, even though the ?12345 is different than the ?67890.

What I'm wondering is, **is there any way I can force the browser to respect the .jpg?12345 and .jpg?67890, and show unique images (because they should have been cached as unique), even though they are both radar_0.jpg**

Thanks very much!

**UPDATE:**

So upon further investigation, it appears as though none of the images are being cached, although they seem to be cached fine during the javascript loop.  The loop is certainly playing fast enough that they're not ALL downloading continuously.  But the images (only 9 of them) seem to be re-downloading when the the shift occurs.  In other words:

[0] = images/radar_0.jpg?67890 <- this loads the NEW radar_0.jpg file (correct)

[1] = images/radar_0.jpg?12345 <- this also loads the NEW radar_0.jpg file (incorrect)

[2] = images/radar_1.jpg?12345 <- this now loads the previous radar_0.jpg file, which is now renamed on the server to radar_1.jpg

[3] = images/radar_2.jpg?12345 <- this now loads the prevous radar_1.jpg file, which is now renamed on the server to radar_2.jpg

...

[9] = images/radar_8.jpg?12345

Note, there is nothing now pointing to images/radar_9.jpg?12345, so the renamed radar_9.jpg (which used to be radar_8.jpg) is not downloaded, which is why I said only 9 images re-download, and not all 10.

If I leave the page up long enough, the array eventually gets shifted out and all of the pointers point to images/radar_0.jpg?... and what comes after the ? is each different.  Yet there is nothing to "loop" anymore, as they're all the same image - radar_0.jpg.

So it appears as though caching is being ignored outright, although i'm not sure why it works for the loop itself.

My HTML header is set up as follows:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-Control" CONTENT="public">
```

Thanks very much to any assistance.

Comment: Can you provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? This is a surprising behavior.

Comment: I'll work on this.  There's a lot of "fat" I can trim to leave the meat and potatoes.  In the mean time, see my update above.  This may provide some additional insight.